# jQuery .click() not binding properly

Tags: jquery

I want to perform some action when a link is clicked, I am using the following code to achieve this however it rarely works.  If I click the link it usually refreshes the page, and 1/10 times it'll actually pop up "Hi".  What is wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#slconfiglink').click(function()
    {
        alert("hi");
        return false;
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="slconfiglink">Config 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the ID's are not replicated elsewhere in the HTML

Comment: are you using the same id on all the links?...as what i see in the code above?

Comment: I just pasted your code into an old jQuery test page of mine, and it works fine. I can't see anything wrong. Have you tried _just_ this code in a single new test page, as an experiment?

Comment: What browser are you using and what is your jQuery version?

Comment: @Piotr 1.4.1 and Firefox. @Matt I have used the same code I pasted on lots of other pages making me wonder whats different about this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to give your `<a>` a valid `href`, like this:

```
<a href="#" id="slconfiglink">Config 1</a>
```

Your anchor needs to have an `href` or a `name` to be valid, otherwise you'll get some funny behavior that'll vary by the browser used.

Also, unless you need the anchor for hover CSS, etc...you have the option to put the click handler right on the `<li>`, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="slconfiglink">Config 1</li>
</ul>
```

A few other things to check, make sure that ID is unique, if it's not use a class, like `class="slconfiglink"` and your selector would be `".slconfiglink"` instead of `"#slconfiglink"`.

If your elements are being added on the fly, change from

```
$('#slconfiglink').click(function() {
```

To use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this (or with the class selector, if the multiple comment applies):

```
$('#slconfiglink').live('click', function() {
```

Comment: @Chris - Updated with some more scenarios to check, see if any apply.

Comment: Thanks Nick, very comprehensive answer however I'm still having no joy.  I moved the ID to the `<li>` but this didn't work either.  The HTML is static so no need for `live()` either.  I'm totally confused as to why it's not working!

Comment: @Chris - have an example page I can take a peek at?

Comment: @Nick - I changed my code to use `live()` instead of `$(document).ready()` and this works... I wonder if, for some reason, `$(document).ready()` is having issues on this particular page?

Comment: @Chris - Are the elements added via ajax or anything?

Comment: Nope, which is weird... I cleaned up all other Javascript stuff on the page and it made no difference... Either way `live()` works and I'm happy with that

Comment: @Chris - very weird indeed, if you get time, I'd run the page through a validator, unclosed tags, etc can throw `document.ready` for a loop: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Is the element being created dynamically? If you are adding it using Javascript, you'll need to reattach your event handler after it's been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Use the preventDefault() method to make sure the browser doesnt follow the link.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#slconfiglink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false` already prevents the default behavior and any bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. 
To solve I've just used simple javascript in combination with jQuery. 
That's what I've done:

```
<script>
    function yourFunction()
    {
        alert("hi");
        //$("#slconfiglink").doWhatYouWant();
    }
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#slconfiglink").attr('onclick', 'yourFunction();')
           //I did it in this way to garantee the function 
           //will only be called after the DOM is ready
    });
</script>

<a id="slconfiglink" href="javascript:;">click me</a>
```

I hope this could be useful! ^^

Answer (score 0):

could you try changing the href of anchor tag to
'javascript:void(0);'